# Twitter Cards: "No card found (Card Error)"

Tags: facebook-opengraph, twitter-card

On Twitter, I can't show an image card when tweeting my website https://startcrowd.club
But it works perfectly on Facebook.

I want to show this card: http://startcrowd.club/images/startcrowdimage.jpg

I tried https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator and I got:

> INFO:  Page fetched successfully
>   INFO:  9 metatags were found
>   ERROR: No card found (Card error)

The relevant metatags on my page https://startcrowd.club/index.html are:

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta property="og:image" content="images/startcrowdimage.jpg">
```

The documentation I followed is:

https://dev.twitter.com/cards/getting-started

Comment: Which card do you try to get? And which documentation do you follow? Does it really say that you only need `og:image`?

Comment: Yes it does. I added those infos to the question

Comment: With "which card" I mean which Twitter Card (e.g., [Summary Card with Large Image](https://dev.twitter.com/cards/types/summary-large-image), [Player Card](https://dev.twitter.com/cards/types/player), …) not which image. The linked documentation doesn’t state that there is a card that only requires `og:image`, does it?

Comment: It's worth noting that Twitter's Card validator is not 100% live, but seems to show results based on cached information. I've made changes to my card meta data and they sometimes took quite a lot of time to show (several hours to a day in many occasions).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add:

```
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
<meta name="twitter:image" content="https://startcrowd.club/images/startcrowdimage.jpg">
```

Doc: https://dev.twitter.com/cards/types/summary-large-image

Answer (score 10):

Ensure that the og:type tag is set. On Facebook it is not required, Facebook will use website as the og:type if it is not found. That is why it worked fine on Facebook.

By adding `<meta property="og:type" content="website">` if the twitter:card property is not set, twitter will use summary.

So just add `<meta property="og:type" content="website">` and I think it will work fine.

PS: I also had the same issue but when I added `<meta property="og:type" content="website">` it worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

You should change your
`twitter:card` tag to '**app**', '**player**', '**summary**' or '**summary_large_image**'

```
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary" />
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@flickr" />
<meta name="twitter:title" content="Small Island Developing States Photo Submission" />
<meta name="twitter:description" content="View the album on Flickr." />
<meta name="twitter:image" content="https://farm6.staticflickr.com/5510/14338202952_93595258ff_z.jpg" />
```

that is all required meta tags.
You can also check it from [twitter validator](https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator)

Here is a article might be helpful

https://medium.com/@melih193/social-media-cards-for-more-interaction-with-meta-tags-741a6e8d27d1

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following before your closing `</head>` will do:

```
<meta content='summary_large_image' name='twitter:card'/>
<meta content='@yourTwitterID' name='twitter:site'/>
<meta content='@yourTwitterID' name='twitter:creator'/>
```

If your `<head></head>` tag contains any `og:xxx` meta tags, the Twitter crawler should be able to grab it. They can't generate a card for you if you don't tell them which Twitter account that this card belongs to. The card needs to generate a link that references back to the account owner.